# INSERT Query - DateTime Param to MSACCESS Table Not Working (ASP.NET)

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, ms-access

## Context:

I'm using a codefile to write all my VB.NET for my ASP.NET web form. My .aspx is attempting to use user input from a form to create a record in my MSACCESS database table. My organization has not purchased Visual Studio so I do all my work in NotePad++ and have no true debugging features available to me.

## Issue:

One of the input text boxes asks for a date, the expected input of which will be validated to follow "M/d/yyyy".

Whenever I attempt to modify or tweak my code to get it to work, I'm always presented with the same error: **"System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."**

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated!!

## Problematic Section:

I should note that whatever issue I find with this code also applies to another Date field I'm using to collect 'Date Due', which you might see in the Full Code section.

```
    Dim prmAdded as OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@DateAdded",OleDbType.DBDate)
    dt = DateTime.ParseExact(newDateAdded.value,"M/d/yyyy", provider)
    prmAdded.Value = dt
    cmd.Parameters.Add(prmAdded)
```

## Notes:

- I broke out the Date object from ParseExact to its own variable,
  'dt', instead of placing directly into 'prmAdded.value' for debugging
  purposes.
- I've tried several other OleDbtypes which produced the same error.
- I've looked at other similar posts here and attempted those solutions, but I continue to get the same error.

## Full Code:

```
    Protected Sub AddTask_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    con.Open()
    Dim strSQL as string, dt as DateTime, provider as CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO Tasks(Task, DateAdded, DateDue)" _
    & "VALUES (@Task,@DateAdded,@DateDue)"

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, con)

    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Task", newTask.value)

    Dim prmAdded as OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@DateAdded",OleDbType.DBDate)
    dt = DateTime.ParseExact(newDateAdded.value,"M/d/yyyy", provider)
    prmAdded.Value = dt
    cmd.Parameters.Add(prmAdded)

    Dim prmDue as OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@DateDue",OleDbType.Date)
    dt = DateTime.ParseExact(newDueDate.value,"M/d/yyyy", provider)
    prmDue.Value = dt
    cmd.Parameters.Add(prmDue)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
    con.Close()
```

Comment: What kinds of entries result in the error?  The issue is with the text entered matching the format supplied, not the `OleDbParameter`

Comment: @Plutonix The entry I'm using which is producing the error is a string of "2/17/2016" from an input box of type='text' on my web page. The input's ID = 'newDateAdded'.

Comment: oh btw.. check this about free visual studio: https://www.visualstudio.com/support/legal/mt171547

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduced your problem, however I crafted a sample which perhaps may help you locate your issue.  It is unclear in your post what data provider you are using and what the input values for Task, DateAdded and DateDue are.

Using your code as a starting point, I created a Microsoft Access database with a `Tasks` table defined as follows:

[image]

`Task`, `DateAdded` and `DateDue` are also all set to `Required`

My code is as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task = new Task();
        task.AddTask("First One", "02/18/2016", "02/21/2016");
    }
}

internal class Task
{
    private OleDbConnection _conn;

    public Task()
    {
        _conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Temp\AccessSample\AccessSample\AppData\Database.accdb;");
    }

    public bool AddTask(string task, string dateAdded, string dateDue)
    {
        _conn.Open();
        string strSQL = "INSERT INTO Tasks(Task, DateAdded, DateDue) VALUES (@Task,@DateAdded,@DateDue)";

        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, _conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Task", task);

            var dateAddedParam = new OleDbParameter("@DateAdded", OleDbType.DBDate);
            var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateAdded, "M/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            dateAddedParam.Value = dt;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(dateAddedParam);

            var dateDueParam = new OleDbParameter("@DateDue", OleDbType.DBDate);
            dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateDue, "M/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            dateDueParam.Value = dt;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(dateDueParam);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        _conn.Close();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note: I am using the 32bit Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0, which means the console application is set to be compiled as x86.